# How do I cut clips using its position from a video?

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-streaming, video-editing

I have a lot of clip positions that I have to extract from a single video, how can I automate the whole process? As of now I have to manually cut each clip using its position, but as my number of videos have increased I need to automate the process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet would be to ask this on the video production exchange.

Comment: video.stackexchange.com, I dont know how to move this

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to do this as it all revolves around time codes (in and out)

if you have the exact timecode point of the points you need to start and stop from you could type them in to the NLE for IN and OUT then cut but I dont think there is a auto way of doing this but I might be wrong